# How to incorporate weighted contexts in context aware recommender system

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I imported the movielens 1m dataset, then built the random-forest classification tree to get context weights.
I want to include these weights (importances) in collaborative filtering algorithm to calculate similarity

```
# Train the random forest classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf.fit(X, y)

# Retrieve feature importance scores
feature_importances = rf.feature_importances_

# Create a dictionary to store feature importance scores
feature_weights = {feature: importance for feature, importance in zip(X.columns,       feature_importances)}

# Prepare the data for collaborative filtering
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(1, 5))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(ratings[['UserID', 'MovieID', 'Rating']], reader)

# Split the data into training and test sets
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Build and train the collaborative filtering model
cf_model = KNNBasic()
cf_model.fit(trainset)

# Generate predictions for the test set using collaborative filtering
cf_predictions = cf_model.test(testset)
print('cf_predictions', cf_predictions)
predictions = []
actual_ratings = []

for prediction in cf_predictions:
user_id = prediction.uid
MovieID = prediction.iid
true_rating = prediction.r_ui

weighted_rating = 0.0
```

## Check if the movie has contextual features

## Here is the problem

#The following condition is always false because  feature weights contain importance values,

## while MovieID is the actual movie id values

```
if MovieID in feature_weights:
    # Calculate the weighted #rating based on the feature importance weight
    weighted_rating = feature_weights[MovieID] * prediction.est
    print('***** movie_id in feature_weights ***** prediction.est:', prediction.est)
else:
    # Use the collaborative filtering prediction
    # print('***** movie_id not in feature_weights ***** prediction.est:', prediction.est)
    weighted_rating = prediction.est

predictions.append(weighted_rating)
actual_ratings.append(true_rating)
Convert predictions to a NumPy array
predictions = np.array(predictions)

Calculate RMSE
rmse = accuracy.rmse(predictions, verbose=True)
print("RMSE:", rmse)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.